# Redux DevTools: Can't open VS Code from Trace tab lines of code

Tags: redux, visual-studio-code, trace, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

My problem is when I am on the Trace tab of Redux DevTools on Chrome and I click on a line of code (for example a dispatch) that the Trace tab allows me to see [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xeJy.png), instead of opening it on VS Code at the correct number line, it opens a new tab on Chrome with the message "A website wants to open this application" with a button "Open Visual Studio Code" but the tab instantly closes/disappears!

I tried several times to click very quickly on the button "Open VS Code" but it doesn't make any difference. I also tried Ctrl + Shift + T to reopened closed tabs but it doesn't reopen that specific tab...

It seems I only need to click on that "Open VS Code" button to make it work. Also I'm a beginner so there's probably something I'm missing.

Here are the values I put on the settings :

[The settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ2L3.png)

Comment: Did you find the solution for it ?  Faced same issue today!

Comment: No unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix the path of your project directory correctly. I've also face the same problem for a while then I found my mistake and resolved the same problem.

1. Here the first step you have to follow check the project directory displaying in reduxDevTool https://prnt.sc/wk4z5f
2. You see the file name like this `.redux-starter/src/index.js:9`(Please check the above screenshot link)
3. Open the reduxDevTools Settings by clicking on settings button from reduxDevTools.
4. Here you have to check the radio **External ediotr** radio button and type `vscode` inside the input field.
5. And finally, most important things you have to setup i.e; is path of your project directory. Copy the project directory path `D:\xampp\htdocs\reactjs\redux\` where the `Redux-Starter` project folder exists and paste it on that `textarea` field.

Lastly, reload the frame, go to Trace tab and click one of the dispatch function. You will see that it opens in the vscode.

Comment: I'm not trying with Redux anymore but thanks for you help. <3